# jsPlumb Toolkit trigger hover event

Tags: jsplumb

How do I trigger a hover event when the div that the lines are connecting is hovered?

In my example, I would like the line to change to red whenever the source or target div his hovered:

http://jsfiddle.net/rt9pkLp3/

I'd also like to change the background-color of both the source and target.

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
    var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
    jQuery.each(edges, function (index, edge) {
        console.log("Connecting: " + edge.source + " to: " + edge.target);
        jsPlumb.connect({ source:edge.source, target:edge.target, paintStyle: blue_line, hoverPaintStyle: red_line });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with that isn't exactly what I wanted, but does work:

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
    var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance();
    jQuery.each(edges, function (index, edge) {
        console.log("Connecting: " + edge.source + " to: " + edge.target);
        jsPlumb.connect({ source:edge.source, target:edge.target });
        jQuery("#" + edge.source + ", #" + edge.target).mouseover(function() {
            jQuery("#" + edge.source).addClass("jsplumb-source-hover");
            jQuery("#" + edge.target).addClass("jsplumb-target-hover");
        }).mouseout(function() {
            jQuery("#" + edge.source).removeClass("jsplumb-source-hover");
            jQuery("#" + edge.target).removeClass("jsplumb-target-hover");
        });
    });
});
```